# replace multiline text between xml tags with awk

Tags: awk

I have an xml file

```
`<private-keys>
    <private-key>
        <name>ssh_host_rsa_key</name>
    </private-key>
    <private-key>
        <name>test_server_pvt_key</name>
        <certificate-chains>
            <certificate-chain>
                <name>server_cert</name>
         <certificate>MIIECTCCAvGgAwIBAgIBCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBjDELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ1ox
FjAUBgNVBAgMDVNvdXRoIE1vcmF2aWExDTALBgNVBAcMBEJybm8xDzANBgNVBAoM
...
J1t4nk9saeo87kIuNEDfYNdwYZzRfXoGJ5qIJQK+uJJv9noaIhfFowDW/G14Ji5p
Vh/YtvnOPh7aBjOj8jmzk8MqzK+TZgT7GWu48Nd/NaV8g/DNg9hlN047LaNsJly3
NX3+VBlpMnA4rKwl1OnmYSirIVh9RJqNwqe6k/k=</certificate>
            </certificate-chain>
        </certificate-chains>
    </private-key>
</private-keys>`
```

I'm trying to come up with a awk or sed which can be used to replace the multi line certificate data `<certificate>...multi line data to be replace...</certificate>`with another multi line block of data, the result will be something like:

```
`<private-keys>
    <private-key>
        <name>ssh_host_rsa_key</name>
    </private-key>
    <private-key>
        <name>test_server_pvt_key</name>
        <certificate-chains>
            <certificate-chain>
                <name>server_cert</name>
     <certificate>MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAueCQaNQWoNmFK6LKu1p8U8ZWdWg/PvDdLsJyzfzl/Qw4UA68
SfFNaY06zZl8QB9W02nr5kWeeMY0VA3adrPgOlvfx3oWlFbkETnMaN4OT3WTQ0Wt
6jAWZDzVfopwpJPAzRPxACDftIqFGagYcF32hZlVNqqnVdbXh0S0EViweqp/dbG4
...
B4f09aeELM2ASIuk8Q/Mx0jQFnm8lzRFXdewgvdPoZW/7VufM9O7dGPOc41cm2Dh
yrTcXx/VmUBb+/fnXVEgCv7gylp/wtdTGHQBQJHR81jFBz0lnLj+gg==</certificate>
            </certificate-chain>
        </certificate-chains>
    </private-key>
</private-keys>`
```

I don't have any advanced regular expression utilities, only linux shell (not even bash) awk and sed are the available tools.

Comment: are you able to install any libraries/packages?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install anything on the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    cert = (NR==1 ? "" : cert ORS) $0
    next
}
sub(/<certificate>.*/,"") {
    beg = $0 "<certificate>"
    inCert = 1
}
inCert {
    if ( sub(/.*<[\/]certificate>/,"") ) {
        end = "</certificate>" $0
        print beg cert end
        inCert = 0
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ cat repl
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAueCQaNQWoNmFK6LKu1p8U8ZWdWg/PvDdLsJyzfzl/Qw4UA68
SfFNaY06zZl8QB9W02nr5kWeeMY0VA3adrPgOlvfx3oWlFbkETnMaN4OT3WTQ0Wt
6jAWZDzVfopwpJPAzRPxACDftIqFGagYcF32hZlVNqqnVdbXh0S0EViweqp/dbG4
...
B4f09aeELM2ASIuk8Q/Mx0jQFnm8lzRFXdewgvdPoZW/7VufM9O7dGPOc41cm2Dh
yrTcXx/VmUBb+/fnXVEgCv7gylp/wtdTGHQBQJHR81jFBz0lnLj+gg==
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk repl file
<private-keys>
    <private-key>
        <name>ssh_host_rsa_key</name>
    </private-key>
    <private-key>
        <name>test_server_pvt_key</name>
        <certificate-chains>
            <certificate-chain>
                <name>server_cert</name>
         <certificate>MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAueCQaNQWoNmFK6LKu1p8U8ZWdWg/PvDdLsJyzfzl/Qw4UA68
SfFNaY06zZl8QB9W02nr5kWeeMY0VA3adrPgOlvfx3oWlFbkETnMaN4OT3WTQ0Wt
6jAWZDzVfopwpJPAzRPxACDftIqFGagYcF32hZlVNqqnVdbXh0S0EViweqp/dbG4
...
B4f09aeELM2ASIuk8Q/Mx0jQFnm8lzRFXdewgvdPoZW/7VufM9O7dGPOc41cm2Dh
yrTcXx/VmUBb+/fnXVEgCv7gylp/wtdTGHQBQJHR81jFBz0lnLj+gg==</certificate>
            </certificate-chain>
        </certificate-chains>
    </private-key>
</private-keys>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in desktop perfectly (gawk I guess). But gives me an error 'awk: bad regex '.*<[': Unmatched [ or [^' on the busybox awk (sorry I haven't specifically mentioned that I'm no a busy box system in my original question).

Comment: @EdMorton It really doesn't work on older busybox versions of awk. Replace `/.*<[/]certificate>/` with `/.*<.certificate>` and it will work (in this case only).

Comment: My apologies, you need to escape the backslash within the bracket expression for portability to all awks. Change `/[/]/` to `/[\/]/`. I've updated the script in my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. This is working. One more question, how do we filter the replacement only happens for the certificate name with `<name>server_cert</name>`. This is something I overlooked, the awk script replaces all the certificates, I only want to replace the `server_cert` certificate.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure I understand what you mean, post a new question with it's own sample input and expected output and clearly stated requirements.