# Change tag values using awk

Tags: awk, tags

I need to change this piece of code:

```bash
NR==FNR {
    cert = (NR==1 ? "" : cert ORS) $0
    next
}
sub(/<named-connections>.*/,"") {
    beg = $0 "<named-connections>"
    inCert = 1
}
inCert {
    if ( sub(/.*<[\/]named-connections>/,"") ) {
        end = "</named-connections>" $0
        print beg cert end
        inCert = 0
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

In order to, instead of changing what's inside the tag `<named-connections>`, change only the connection tag

```xml
<named-connections>
  <named-connection caption='xyz' name='05mqr9a0muzjns11387v9142owuo'>
    <connection authentication='RDBMS' class='oracle' one-time-sql=''  oracle.net.ssl_version='' port='10000' schema='PARSE' server='xyz.z' server-oauth='' service='abc'        sslmode='require' username='DBABA' workgroup-auth-mode='prompt' />
  </named-connection>
</named-connections>
```

Any ideas?

We have this for cycle that goes to a txt file, reads all rows, changes the tag inside and saves the new file as .tds:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (trim0ext.txt) do ( 
set "file5=%%f"
awk -f xmlcode.awk %_configPRD% "!file5!.txt" > "!file5!.tds"
```

The output after should be something like this:

```xml
<named-connections>
  <named-connection caption='xyz' name='05mqr9a0muzjns11387v9142owuo'>
    <connection authentication='RDBMS' class='oracle' one-time-sql=''  oracle.net.ssl_version='' port='new_value' schema='PARSE' server='new_value' server-oauth='' service='new_value'        sslmode='require' username='new_value' workgroup-auth-mode='prompt' />
  </named-connection>
</named-connections>
```

Comment: `awk` is not XML/HTML parser

Comment: Show us XML/HTML before and after (expected output).

Comment: The before values are already there, the tags that I shared. After running this piece of code, another script will change the line/tag of the connection with the correct values.

Comment: Show us the values **after** then

Comment: We have this for cycle that goes to a txt file, reads all rows, changes the tag inside and saves the new file as .tds 
 for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (trim0ext.txt) do (
 set "file5=%%f"
 awk -f xmlcode.awk %_configPRD% "!file5!.txt" > "!file5!.tds"
)

Comment: The output after should be something like this: 
<named-connections>
      <named-connection caption='xyz' name='05mqr9a0muzjns11387v9142owuo'>
        <connection authentication='RDBMS' class='oracle' one-time-sql=''  oracle.net.ssl_version='' port='new_value' schema='PARSE' server='new_value' server-oauth='' service='new_value'  sslmode='require' username='new_value' workgroup-auth-mode='prompt' />
      </named-connection>
</named-connections>"

Comment: please update the question with the additional details; not everyone is going to read the comments to piece together the bigger picture; also, formatting is lost in comments which in turn can lead to confusion

Comment: That piece of code looks familiar - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50088524/1745001 :-). When posting code you got from other people it'd be useful for you to [edit] your question to at least provide the link to the answer you got it from so we have some more context especially if, as in the original question, you don't have access to any XML-aware tools.

Answer (score 0):

To update the `port` attribute, by example, using a proper `xml` parser:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//connection/@port' -v NEW file.xml
```

To edit *in place*, use `-L`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u '//connection/@port' -v NEW file.xml
```

Output, pretty printed:

```
<named-connections>
  <named-connection caption="xyz" name="05mqr9a0muzjns11387v9142owuo">
      <connection authentication="RDBMS"
                  class="oracle"
                  one-time-sql=""
                  oracle.net.ssl_version=""
                  port="NEW"                   <!-- UPDATED -->
                  schema="PARSE"
                  server="xyz.z"
                  server-oauth=""
                  service="abc"
                  sslmode="require"
                  username="DBABA"
                  workgroup-auth-mode="prompt"/>
  </named-connection>
</named-connections>
```